# Unable to import template

Tags: python, templates, flask

I am a Flask beginner, please excuse me if the answer to my question is obvious.

I have been working on a project using an OVH server. I have been using this tutorial to set up a first "Hello world": https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/web-power/python-install-flask/

Here is the structure of my project :

```
www/
  venv/
  myapp.py
```

At this point, everything is working fine. When I connect to my website, it shows a good "Hello, world !" as expected.
However I now want to add a template to my page, I have therefore added a few lines :

```
this_file = "venv/bin/activate_this.py"
exec(open(this_file).read(), {'__file__': this_file})

from flask import Flask, render_template

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/')
@application.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I have imported render_template and changed from "return 'Hello'" to "return render_template('index.html')".

**Unfortunately, my website now displays "Incomplete response received from application".** I have tried these 2 structures :

```
www/
  venv/
  myapp.py
templates/
  index.html
```

and :

```
www/
  templates/
     index.html
  venv/
  myapp.py
```

But it doesn't change anything... Does any know how to return a template?

Comment: activate your environment in the cmd and then run your app there don't use `exec` especially if it is not needed and I am very sure that it is not needed

Answer (score 0):

instead of starting the venv up from within the program with

```
this_file = "venv/bin/activate_this.py"
exec(open(this_file).read(), {'__file__': this_file})
```

(works only on mac/Linux) you might want to do that in the terminal instead,
as

```
venv/bin/activate
```

source: https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/26/python-virtual-env/

then, to run your file, you can add this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/')
@application.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=True)
```

the last lines are good habit for projects like these, debugger on is extremely useful. Your structure is fine. I understand why you might want to add the first few lines, I am working on a venv flask app too. However, I tried implementing the windows version of those lines, which did not work... even if that works fine for you, please consider adding

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=True)
```

either way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I have added ''' if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=True)'''.

Regarding ```this_file = "venv/bin/activate_this.py"
exec(open(this_file).read(), {'__file__': this_file})```, if I remove this piece of code, it does not work anymore... Even if, while connected by ssh to my server I have run the code ```source venv/bin/activate```... Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: It seems like this is related to the fact that Im using OVH cloud web server. When I am working on a local server, I dont need to add ```this_file = "venv/bin/activate_this.py" exec(open(this_file).read(), {'__file__': this_file})``` and I can load templates without any issue...

Comment: @Guliup to be honest, with your work on the server you are further than me, I have no idea how to handle such things yet. I have tried implementing those lines in a testfile, but that was exactly why it broke down for me... so I'd say remove those lines, but if that is your only option... last option is maybe ```venv\Lib\activate``` or ```venv\Lib\activate.bat``` but that is all I know